# Selenium cannot find ul Element that is visible on Page

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently testing an email service, and upon opening a list of options to filter email, I want to be able to automate clicking on an option in the list. The code for the list is:

[image]

However, selenium cannot find this element, even though I can find it by searching the HTML using CTRL+F. The code I'm currently using to try and find and click this list element is:

```
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.myorg.automation.Objects.ManageEmails.Locators.FilterList));
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(org.myorg.automation.Objects.ManageEmails.Locators.FilterList));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Unread");
```

The xpath of the list is:

```
/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul
```

Any help would really be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a select in this case and the: Select dropdown = new Select(); wont work. You'll need a custom method to select a value from that list

```
 public class Testing {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void TestSomething() {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("<the url where this list is present>");

        // assuming that the ul list is unique on the page if not find another way to get it       
        WebElement ulListParent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'ms-ContextualMenu-list is-open')]"));
        
        SelectBasedOnValue(ulListParent, "Unread");

        driver.close();

    }

    public void SelectBasedOnValue(WebElement parentElement, String optionValue) {

        parentElement.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//li[text()='%s']", optionValue))).click();
        

    }

}
```